# Guide me on How to enable Multiple domain Masking on a single page/file

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, cpanel, whm

I am using CENTOS 7.8 (WHM/Cpanel)

Can anyone please guide me on how can anyone land their domain/subdomain after setting CNAME of my domain without changing their URL?

Example - my website is content.example.com

if someone points their subdomain mypics.mysite.in using cname then it should browse content.example.com without changing URL.

Comment: With a common VirtualHost setup, you will probably need to add `mypics.mysite.in` as a ServerAlias, so that your server knows which content to serve.